# Custom handler on IIS 7.5 doesn't work

Tags: iis-7.5

I am new to IIS 7.5. I have an application in asp.net 2.0, which has its own custom URL rewriting mechanism. All the requests on the browser with .htm will be mapped to .aspx. It works fine on IIS 6, but somehow I could not get it working on IIS 7.5. On IIS 6, I go to Application Properties>Configuration>Mappings and add a new extension .htm with the executable as aspnet_isapi.dll

On IIS 7.5 i added a handler mapping, with path as .htm and executable as aspnet_ispai.dll

But the request does not even come to global.asax. If i try the URL with .aspx extension, pages load properly. Any idea how to set up custom mappings in iis 7.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After selecting Application Pool "Managed pipeline mode" to classic, it started working fine. By default it was set to "Integrated"

Answer (score 0):

```
  You can use handlers for both mode. Also check 
  ApplicationPool -> Advanced Settings
 Enable 32bit code:true
```

if you are building in 32bit machine and hosting in 64bit machine

```
     <!--handler for classic mode-->
    <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.js.axd" type="ScriptTranslator" />
    </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
```